# Access an external variable from (ajax) success function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I need to rewrite html code after success function of an ajax code get fired, but I don't have any id or class to identify the element, only can get a `$(this)`.

In my html I have(I can only customize the content of the div. I don't want to write a class because there a lot of records to modify and a complex structure.):

```
<div class="jtable-input jtable-custom-input">
    <a onclick="ReWriteInputControl(' + data.record.Codigo + ', $(this))">Delete File</a>
</div>
```

In my javascript:

```
function ReWriteInputControl(code, container) {
    //here I can get the parent, etc.
    //$(container).parent().empty().append('<input type="file" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="myFile"/>') works

    var $parentContainer = $(container);

    $.ajax({
        url: "RemoveFileFromTeacher",
        data: { id: code },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                //Here I need to do
                //$(container).parent().empty().append('<input type="file" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="myFile"/>') but don't work
                //$parentContainer also didn't work
            }
            else {
            }
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

In success function what I need to do to access container variable.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Can you not add an `id` to the container? Also the `$(this)` will be identifying the `<a>` element, not the container; you'd need `$(this).parent('div')` for that.

Comment: @Kahan The name of the identifier is wrong, I can't add an id to the div.

Comment: Of course you can access them `$parentContainer` variable from the success listener - does it really throw a Reference Error? What do you mean by "*didn't work*", are you sure the success function is called at all (and not the fail callback)? Do you get any error messages?